# Is it possible to set a fact of a list in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to set a fact containing a list in Ansible using `set_fact`? What's the correct syntax for it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Indeed it is.  You  need to quote the entire list though:

```yaml
- name: set fact
  set_fact: foo="[ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]"

- name: debug
  debug: msg={{ item }}
  with_items: foo
```

The above tasks should generate the following output:

```
TASK: [set fact] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [debug] *****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=one) => {
    "item": "one",
    "msg": "one"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=two) => {
    "item": "two",
    "msg": "two"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=three) => {
    "item": "three",
    "msg": "three"
}
```

Answer (score 44):

Yes, this is possible.  As mentioned in another answer, you can set an array using double quotes, like so:

```yaml
- name: set foo fact to a list
  set_fact: 
    foo: "[ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]"
```

However, I thought I'd create another answer to indicate that it's also possible to add to an existing array, like so:

```yaml
- name: add items to foo list fact
  set_fact: 
    foo: "{{ foo + ['four'] }}"
```

Combining these and adding debugging as a playbook (which I'm calling `facts.yml`) like so:

```yaml
---
- name: test playbook
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: set foo fact to an array
      set_fact: 
        foo: "[ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]"
    - debug: 
        var: foo
    - name: add items to foo array fact
      set_fact: 
        foo: "{{ foo + [ 'four' ] }}"
    - debug: 
        var: foo
```

Produces (via `ansible-playbook facts.yml`) the following:

```
PLAY [test playbook] ******************************************************** 

TASK: [set foo fact to an array] ********************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [debug var=foo] *******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "foo": [
        "one", 
        "two", 
        "three"
    ]
}

TASK: [add items to foo array fact] *****************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [debug var=foo] *******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "foo": [
        "one", 
        "two", 
        "three", 
        "four"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************** 
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Great answer... one question though - how the !!?!? are we supposed to know about this? I don't see anything like this in the documentation

Comment: appending items to facts is really valuable, been searching for a while to find this

Comment: How does this work if we start with `foo=[]` and then append a templated string instead of `'four'`?  For example, i'll offer an "answer" below to explain this question.

Comment: FWIW this doesn't work on `ansible [core 2.13.7]`: outputs `ok: [localhost] => {
    "foo": "[ 'one', 'two', 'three' ] + [ 'four' ]"
}`

Comment: `"{{foo}} + [ 'four' ]"` is risky as it could include the array as a literal string if `foo` is not a list, you should use `"{{ foo + [ 'four' ] }}"` instead.

Answer (score 20):

Adding to the already given answers I would like to show you a different way to
define a list with `set_fact` using the regular YAML syntax instead of the
custom format which Ansible core folks like to use in their docs.  This
custom format, like in this case, has shown lead to confusion.

Consider this example:

```yaml
- name: 'Set the foo variable to a static list using the YAML syntax'
  set_fact:
    foo:
      - 'one'
      - 'two'
      - 'three'
```

Straight forward, right? Just as you would do in any normal YAML document. So
why not use it in Ansible YAML tasks file too?

About the combination of lists mentioned by @lindes-hw. There is more than one
way to do this. The following examples use Jinja2 syntax to define the list:

```yaml
- name: 'Set the foo variable to a combined static list using the Jinja2 syntax'
  set_fact:
    foo: '{{ [ "one" ] + [ "two", "three" ] }}'

- name: 'Set the foo variable to a combined static list using the Jinja2 syntax and Jinja2 filters'
  set_fact:
    foo: '{{ [ "one" ] | union([ "two", "three" ]) }}'
```

The second example uses the `union` filter. Refer to the [set theory filters in the Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters).

Comment: +1 for keeping it simple. One of the major selling points of Ansible is that you can use easy to read (and write) YAML syntax, so it always boggles me why lots of Ansible example code is convoluted for no appearant reason.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar requirement to create list of server objects based on list of IP addresses.

```
vars:
  server_ips: one,two,three
tasks:
  - name: build items list
    set_fact: 
      foo: "{{foo|default([]) + [{'ip': {'addr': item, 'type': 'V4'}}] }}"
    with_items: "{{server_ips.split(',')}}"
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ foo }}"
```

Gives following output

```
TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [build items list] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=one)
ok: [localhost] => (item=two)
ok: [localhost] => (item=three)

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "ip": {
                "addr": "one", 
                "type": "V4"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "ip": {
                "addr": "two", 
                "type": "V4"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "ip": {
                "addr": "three", 
                "type": "V4"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: why not just put your fact under vars instead of using defaults?

Comment: nice and clean for building an array in a set_fact loop, although not an answer to the OP, this is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Pure gold, indeed!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if the functionality changed --- it possibly did in 2.5 --- but it looks to me like this code

```
with_items: foo
```

in the example doesn't work any more you have to use

```
with_items: "{{ foo }}"
```

I'm using Ansible 2.5.2.  I was getting this (incorrect) output:

```
ok:[localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg":"foo"
}
```

I found the updated syntax in the docs here:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-items

Answer (score 3):

like this

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      redis_list: |
        {%- set list = [] -%}
        {%- for index in range(1, 5 ) -%}
          {{ list.append(index)  }}
        {%- endfor -%}
        {{ list }}
```