# Create a fact that summarizes content from each host a play runs against in an inventory?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to start a service on a series of hosts. The requestor for this Ansible play wants an email (only one email) sent at the end of the play summarizing the status of the service for each given host in the inventory. In order to do this, I need to create some sort of method for storing the information about the status of the service for each host as Ansible processes it to use in this summary email.

In essence, if I was talking about about say Java I would need to have a variable that is then added to by a copy of itself plus additional content over a loop (think this is a maybe compound assignment operator?) . I.E

(string) service status = service status + current hosts status

or

(string) service status += current host status

When I try something like the above and "print out" the value of a "Summary" fact in my playbook it only returns information on the service from the *latest* host in the inventory for example

I want:

host1:
Service Status - good

host 2:
Service Status - good

host 3:
Service Status - good

I get:

host 3:
Service Status - good

Is there a way to do this in Ansible?

I have tried the following:

```
   - name: Get current status  
      shell: /usr/app/current/app/bin/status_script.sh status 
      register: app_status

   - name: Create an empty fact one time and locally to store our summary email text
      set_fact: 
        Summary: " "
        cacheable: yes
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: Populate the fact with more information for each host we check the status on 
      set_fact:
        Summary: " {{ Summary }}  {{ app_status.stdout_lines }} "
        cacheable: yes
      delegate_to: localhost
```

I have looked at the following:

[Is it possible to set a fact of an array in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507589/is-it-possible-to-set-a-fact-of-an-array-in-ansible)

[Ansible set_fact array and populate it from in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631390/ansible-set-fact-array-and-populate-it-from-in-loop)

[How to assign an array to a variable in an Ansible-Playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798382/how-to-assign-an-array-to-a-variable-in-an-ansible-playbook)

Please note I am only using facts inside the context of the same play.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess you want either to update your final `set_fact:` to loop over all hosts in the (playbook, or some group) and extract their facts into one consolidated fact, or to otherwise use a separate play after your "main" one

Something akin to:

```yaml
    - name: Populate the fact with more information for each host we check the status on 
      set_fact:
        AllSummaries: |
           {%- for h in groups["all"] %}
           {{ hostvars[h].Summary }}  {{ hostvars[h].app_status.stdout_lines }}
           {%- endfor -%}
        cacheable: yes
      run_once: yes
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: still working on this solution will let you know if it works